# Codeigniter search with join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tankauth

I'm not sure why this code isn't working, so any help would be appreciated.

I want to search for a users username and also show the name of their character, which is store in the profile table.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

$this->db->join('user_profiles', 'user_profiles.id = users.id');
$this->db->like('username',$search);
$this->db->or_like('user_profiles.character_name',$search);
$data['users'] = $this->db->get('users');
```

The page seems to fire fine without any errors, but no matter what I type into the search I get 0 results.

Solved: Nothing wrong with code, it was my form validation.

Comment: Can you run `echo $this->db->last_query();` and add the actual query which is run to your question please?

Comment: That helped me solve the problem, my form validation rules were breaking everything.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Shall I post my comment as an answer or will you be posting your solution?

Comment: Post it as an answer, the solution isn't really a solution.  I had just set the wrong criteria for validation. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you run the following after your `$this->db->get()`

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

This will allow you to debug your query which is being run. This will highlight problems with input criteria and the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that it is better to rewrite your POST array assigment to

```
$search = $this->input->post('search');
```

And something more - if this is a model, you'd better call that method with the search term as a variable and return the result as object or array to a controller. Written like that you break the MVS paradigm.